# Xlookup and return value not from the same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to use XLOOKUP lookup and return value that are not on the same row?

Table 1 is the dataset that I'm trying use to look up from Table 2.

In Table 1 colA value ="1" is  the Parent, and "2" is the Child. And, the parent row containing the address.

example 1
Lookup Value Table2.A3
Lookup Array Table1.colB
Return Array Table1.C3 & D3

example 2
Lookup Value Table2.A4
Lookup Array Table1.colB
Return Array Table1.C5 & D5

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output for lookup value "CCFF"?

Comment: CCFF return value will be the same as EFGG, which is the value from table1.C5

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use?

Comment: Using Excel 365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
Found the formula from another forum.
H2=XLOOKUP(1,$A$2:INDEX($A$2:$A$100,MATCH($G2,$B$2:$B$100,0)),C$2:INDEX(C$2:C$100,MATCH($G2,$B$2:$B$100,0)),"No match",0,-1)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `XLOOKUP()`, use `INDEX(MATCH())` and increment or decrement the row by 1 (or even a *second* `MATCH()` to find the amount it should change by, though this would be pretty gross)

```
INDEX ( <return array> , MATCH ( <lookup value> , <lookup array> , 0) + 1)
```

**example 2**
Assuming a lookup from Cell B3 in Sheet2 to example 1 Sheet1

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C3:C:10000, MATCH(A3, Sheet1!B3:B10000, 0) - 1)
```

Comment: What if I'm trying to lookup table2.A5 value and want to return table1.C5? That formula will return the value "Sarah" instead

Comment: Just move the increment and decrement until it works out how you want, you can also shift the result array as [**@Jody Highroller** suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69400051/4541045)

Comment: @ti7 - my guess is that the increment isn't consistent, but that OP wants to return a value from the first row above where the match is found where column B is blank.

Comment: mm - such a thing is normally best done by adding another column to find the relative offset .. I suppose they could dynamically add that to their index, but the whole thing seems like there could be other source data in better shape

Comment: In Table 1 colA value ="1" is  the Parent row , and "2" is the Child row. And, the parent row containing the address.

Answer (score 0):

Just offset your return_array parameter.

```
=XLOOKUP(A3,$F$3:$F$7,$G$2:$H$6)
```

[image]

Comment: @BigBen 100% correct.

Comment: "CCFF return value will be the same as EFGG, which is the value from table1.C5"